# mod_rewrite: Redirect request to subdir with many subfolders of different structures + redirect to index.php

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to create a following rule to place in my .htaccess

1. For each request i'd like to execute file/path in subfolder subdir.
2. If the file doesn't exist there then i'd like to forward this request to index.php

Let say that .htaccess iw placed at http://domain/folder

When the user opens url http://domain/folder/Subfolder/xxx.html
he should recieve file from http://domain/folder/subdir/Subfolder/xxx.html

So these rules have to consider the fact that there are subfolders inside subdir.
(Different structures of subfolders :-)
And only if the path under subdir doesn't exist the request should be forwarded to index.php

Plase help :)

ps This is a followup question to my previous one. It is quite different and includes the fact that there are subfolders inside subdir.
-> [mod_rewrite: How to search in local folder, subfolder and then redirect to index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327144/mod-rewrite-how-to-search-in-local-folder-subfolder-and-then-redirect-to-index)

Comment: It would help an answer considerably, if you could elaborate a litte, in which ways the current answers do not solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ([\w]+\.[\w]+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 -f 
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L] 

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdir%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^ /subdir%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

---

#### An update with a slight optimization.

```
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^[^/]+\.[^/]+$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.*/)([\w]+\.[\w]+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1subdir/%2 -f
RewriteRule ^ subdir/%2 [L]

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

- The above will work with anydirectory/subdir

Change log:

- RewriteBase commented for use of relative path.
- Checking for /file.ext (or whether in current directory).
  the below will check  whether file is present in current directory.

  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f`
  `RewriteRule ^[^/]+\.[^/]+$ - [NC,L]`
- > RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdir%{REQUEST_URI} -f

  captures current directory in %1 and the file.ext in %2

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply use an Alias:

```
Alias /folder /subdir
```

And redirect to index.php in your 404 page? It has the advantage, 404 is still caught into the weblog.

Comment: Because i need to deploy Zend Framework based app in an environment where root http public folder is the root of the whole virtual file system. And I don't want to rewrite the whole application.

Comment: so the url mapping should only apply, if matching your http://domain/folder/Subfolder/xxx.html scheme? So better use a RewriteRule than?

Comment: why would you need to rewrite the application?

Comment: mapping should apply to every request. If file/path is found under subdir folder then this file should be returned otherwise request should be redirected to index.php.

Comment: I use a lot of paths to files located inside public folder of ZF. I don't want to update those paths each time i need to adapt my app to new server environment. It is possible, I almost got the solution with my previous question.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the `root/folder` directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /folder

#capture the Subfolder/file.xx
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^/]+/([^/]+)$
#if the subdir/subfolder/file.xx exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdir/%1 -f  
#Serve this file
RewriteRule ^ /subdir/%1 [L,S=1]
#else send to index.php in root directory  
RewriteRule ^  /index.php [L]
```

I am assuming you want to send the request to the index.php in the root dir. If it is in the folder directory instead, change the last rule to

```
RewriteRule ^  index.php [L]
```